# initializer-string for array of chars is too long error

Tags: c++, blackjack

I am working on a BlackJack Game using C++, and I have the following piece of code within it where I am getting an error

```
typedef struct
{
    int value;
    char suit[8];
    char name[8];
}Deck;


Deck Cards[52] = {{ 1,"Ace","Hearts"},{ 2, "Two","Hearts"}, { 3, "Three", "Hearts"}, { 4, "Four","Hearts"}, { 5,"Five","Hearts"},{ 6,"Six", "Hearts06"},
{ 7,"Seven","Hearts"},{ 8,"Eight","Hearts"},{ 9,"Nine","Hearts"},{ 10,"Ten","Hearts"},{10,"Jack","Hearts"},{10,"Queen","Hearts"},{10,"King","Hearts"},
{ 1,"Ace","Clubs"},{2, "Two", "Clubs"},{3,"Three","Clubs"},{4,"Four","Clubs"},{5,"Five","Clubs"},{6,"Six","Clubs"},{7,"Seven","Clubs"},{8,"Eight","Clubs"},
{ 9,"Nine","Clubs"},{10,"Ten","Clubs"},{10,"Jack","Clubs"},{10,"Queen","Clubs"},{10,"King","Clubs"},
{ 1,"Ace","Diamonds"},{2,"Two","Diamonds"},{3,"Three","Diamonds"},{4,"Four","Diamonds"},{5,"Five","Diamonds"},{6,"Six","Diamonds"},{7,"Seven","Diamonds"},
{ 8,"Eight","Diamonds"},{9,"Nine","Diamonds"},{10,"Ten","Diamonds"},{10,"Jack","Diamonds"},{10,"Queen","Diamonds"},{10,"King","Diamonds"},
{ 1,"Ace","Spades"},{ 2,"Two","Spades"},{3,"Three","Spades"},{4,"Four","Spades"},{5,"Five","Spades"},{6,"Six","Spades"},{7,"Seven","Spades"},
{ 8,"Eight","Spades"},{ 9,"Nine","Spades"},{10,"Ten","Spades"},{10,"Jack","Spades"},{10,"Queen","Spades"},{10,"King","Spades"}};
```

The **error** is

```
Main.c:39:127: error: initializer-string for array of chars is too long [-fpermissive]
```

**Line 39** is the last line in the code posted above

Please help me in figuring out why the compiler is throwing an error

Comment: Shouldn't the size of the array be 52? Also I assume "Hearts06" was not what you wanted.

Comment: You could use `std::string`s and `std::vector`s. Then you couldn't make mistakes with array sizes.

Comment: @drescherjm it is 52 in the code, I was experimenting by changing it, I have edited the question

Comment: Have fun programming the logic whereby an Ace can be treated as 1 or 11

Comment: @CashCow If you can't help, then please don't. I was asking for help to figure out what was causing the error, and not to do code review for best practices for implementing BlackJack in C++

Comment: The question had been answered, although you might notice that you have put "suits" and "names" the wrong way round. The compiler won't help you on that, it doesn't know what is a suit and what is a name.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The string `"Diamonds"` has 9 characters including the null terminating character. Therefore, `name` must have at least 9 elements.

However, it looks like your `name` member should be called `suit` and vice versa.

Comment: Forgot to consider the terminating null character, thanks, it worked!

Comment: Yes in the way he is initialising it, although of course diamonds is a suit.

Plus of course this really is not the way to handle the situation

Comment: @CashCow I didn't even notice.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
int nMyArray[8]= {5,6,5,4,6,7,4,2};
```

Prefer this:

```
int nMyArray[]= {5,6,5,4,6,7,4,2};
```

When you are initializing an array. The former one requires you to specify size. The latter one computes the size (at compile time only).