# I cannot give string value to a string variable in this code. Why? I also didn't understand the error meessage

Tags: c, compiler-errors

FYI, I'm new to programming.
When I try to compile this code it gives error saying:

```
[Warning] non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
[Error] initializer-string for array of chars is too long [-fpermissive]
```

I have searched a lot but all of the articles use this exact method. Can anyone explain why am I getting this error? Explain in language I can understand. I didn't understand most of the answers and reasons stated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct person{
    char name[] = "something";  
};
int main(){
    struct person per;
    printf("%s",per.name);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [initializer-string for array of chars is too long error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407898/initializer-string-for-array-of-chars-is-too-long-error)

Comment: @Renat it does not have anything in common with the OPs problem

Comment: @Renat No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Simply - because C language does not allow it as C does not have constructors. You need to initialize the variables yourself when you define them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct person{
    char name[100];  
};
int main(){
    struct person per = {.name = "something"};
    printf("%s",per.name);
}
```

Comment: Shows another error as: [Error] C99 designator 'name' outside aggregate initializer